# Where is struct rq in kernel scheduling code (linux)??/

Tags: linux, struct, scheduling

As a part of an assignment, I have to modify the scheduling policy of linux. I have 3.4.11. I have been programming it, but after a lot of efforts, I haven't been able to find struct rq. By observing the code, I have made a list of variables that struct rq might have as members. I have looked it up in lxr.linux.no but I haven't found any relevant results. Where is this struct rq?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`struct rq` is defined in `kernel/sched/sched.h` ([lines 341-470 in 3.7-rc8](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=kernel/sched/sched.h;h=7a7db09cfabc18af1b35dd2bee57bf60d4103cf4;hb=b69f0859dc8e633c5d8c06845811588fe17e68b3#l341))

Comment: Obvious Correction: path should  kernel/sched/sched.h